# Ruby on Rails - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been making a blog system in Rails while learning the basics of Rails. However, I have encountered an error: "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" in Posts' "show" view, as I want the comment form to be below the contents of the post. I have tried every solution to the problem including browsing other people's responses on Stack Overflow, however so far to no avail.

**CommentsController.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:comment[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    if @comments.save
      flash[:success] = "Your comment has been successfully created."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
      redirect_to @post
    end
  end

  def edit
   @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update_attributes
      flash[:success] = "Your comment has been successfully updated."
      redirect_to user_path
    else
      redirect_to user_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Your comment has been successfully deleted."
      redirect_to post_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Oops! Something went wrong. Try again."
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end

end
```

**show.html.erb (posts)**

```
<div class="show_post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2 class="heading">
            <%= @post.title %>
        </h2>

        <%= raw(@post.content) %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
        <h4>
            Liked this post? Add a comment below!
        </h4>

    <%= form_for(@comment) do |c| %> # Line that raises the error
      <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2>
            <%= "#{pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error")} errors were detected in your form:" %>
          </h2>
     <ul>
        <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li>
           <%= message %>
       </li>
        <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= c.label :content, "Your comment goes here: " %>
    <%= c.cktext_area :content, rows: 10, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= c.submit "Add Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
        <h3>
            Comments:
        </h3>
            <% if @comments && @comments.any? %>
                <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
                    <%= raw(comment.content) %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'

  get 'help' => 'pages#help'
  get 'contact' => 'pages#contact'

  get '/index' => 'users#index'
  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  post '/users' => 'users#create'
  get '/show' => 'users#show'

  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' =>'sessions#create'
  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/new_post' => 'posts#new'
  post '/new_post' => 'posts#create'
  get '/show_post' => 'posts#show'
  get '/delete_post' => 'posts#destroy'

  resources :users

  resources :posts 
  resources :comments
```

I'm still a n00b in Rails, so I need help with solving this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `@comment` in your show view is `nil`. Set it in the controller action to new comment:

```
def show
  #...
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

Comment: That helped! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your comment form appears in the User Show view, you have to specify the @comment instance variable in the the show action of the User Controller or else Rails doesn't know what @comment means.

```
UserController.rb

def show
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

The @post variable in your create action will cause an error because there is no comment id in the user show action (user/1/show). You will have to find a way to pass the comments id to your comment create action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a show method in your CommentsController class. The show view is called from the show method. The error arises because you haven't initialized the @comment instance variable anywhere. So that's why it's complaining saying @comment is nil.

Simply put this method into your controller

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```